# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

the code work but the console log show **Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null**

It cannot be seen in jsfiddle.net, btw here is the demo of what I want.

http://jsfiddle.net/cw6cgg27/

because the markup suck, so I have to find every nodevalue of br, and get rip off line that start with 作詞, 作曲, 編曲, and 監製. It work but why in the console log there is an error?

```
$('br').each(function () {
    if ((this.nextSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('作詞') > -1) || (this.nextSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('作曲') > -1) || (this.nextSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('編曲') > -1) || (this.nextSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('監製') > -1)) {

        $(this.nextSibling).remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is complaining that `nextSibling` does not exist. You must code defensively.

```
$('br').each(function () {
    if (!this.nextSibling) {
      return;
    }
    var nodeValue = this.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();
    var invalid = ['', '作詞', '作曲', '編曲', '監製'];
    if (invalid.indexOf(nodeValue) !== -1) {
        $(this.nextSibling).remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Note that my usage of `Array.indexOf` exists for Internet Explorer 9+. So if you need to support IE8 you must use a polyfill or a different implementation.

Comment: this is brilliant thanks! but I got a question, why is there a <br><br> at the begging after the execution? I thought their were removed? http://jsfiddle.net/cw6cgg27/2/

Comment: Because there is a text element between the br elements. The first br has a nextSibling which is a text element, the nextSibling is not the next br. That text element just happens to be an empty string.

Comment: how to remove that thing then?

Comment: You are removing `br` elements which are followed by certain text. To remove `br` followed by empty text is the same thing! If this.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim() == '' then remove the br and the empty text node.

Comment: Can u update the code? I tried      var nodeValue = this.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim(); it doesn't work

Comment: OK, edited. Added `trim`, and added `''` to the list.

Comment: I got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null

Answer (score 0):

I think changing your code into this would work:

```
$('br').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue.indexOf('作詞') > -1);
});
```